# automapper specify a rule for mapping one property type to another

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a set of business objects that I need to persist as entities.  The business objects have many properties of type TimeSpan.  I would like to map them to long properties on my entities.

```
public class BusinessObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan ProcessingTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan WaitTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan RecordTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long ProcessingTime { get; set; }
        public long WaitTime { get; set; }
        public long RecordTime { get; set; }
    }

    public void CreateMapping()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessObject, Entity>()
            .ForMember(e => e.ProcessingTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProcessingTime.TotalMilliseconds))
            .ForMember(e => e.WaitTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WaitTime.TotalMilliseconds))
            .ForMember(e => e.RecordTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RecordTime.TotalMilliseconds));
    }
```

Is there a way that I can specify in the mapping that all Timespan properties should be mapped to long for that mapping, without having to write out each one?

Comment: "Is there a way that I can specify in the mapping that all Timespan properties should be mapped to long for that mapping, without having to write out each one?" Reflection?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can override the `TypeConverter` that is instantiated for the type `TimeSpan` in 
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/TypeConverterMapper.cs